# Automatic Differentiation in C# and F#

Tags: c#, f#, automatic-differentiation

I am having a problem getting Automatic Differentiation to work between C# and F#.

In C# I have a function that takes a double and returns a double, say:

```
private double Price(double yield)
{
    double price;

    price = 0;

    for (int index = 1; index <= _maturity * _frequency; index++)
    {
        price += (_coupon / _frequency) * _nominal / Math.Pow(1 + (yield / _frequency), index);
    }

    price += _nominal / Math.Pow(1 + (yield / _frequency), _maturity * _frequency);

    return price;
}
```

I picked this function specifically, as the Math.pow is very prohibitive, and only allows a double's or int's for its parameters.

I would like to differentiate this function using Automatic Differentiation. I have written the method for this in F#:

```
type Diff(d : double, df : Lazy<Diff>) = class
    member x.d = d
    member x.df = df
    static member (+) (x : Diff, y : Diff) = 
        Diff(x.d + y.d, lazy (x.df.Value + y.df.Value)) 
    static member (-) (x : Diff, y : Diff) = 
        Diff(x.d - y.d, lazy (x.df.Value - y.df.Value))
    static member (*) (x : Diff, a : double) = 
        Diff(x.d * a, lazy (x.df.Value * a))
    static member (*) (x : Diff, y : Diff) = 
        Diff(x.d * y.d, lazy ((x.df.Value * y) + (y.df.Value * x)))
    override x.ToString() =
        x.d.ToString()
end

let rec dZero = Diff(0.0, lazy dZero)

let dConst x = Diff(x, lazy dZero)

let dId x = Diff(x, lazy dConst 1.0)

let Differentiate (x:Diff) = x.df.Value

// Example function
let f (x:Diff) = x*x*x;

// Example usage:
// (f (dId 5)).ToString = "125"
// (Differentiate (f (dId 5))).ToString = "75"
// (Differentiate (Differentate (f (dId 5)))).ToString = "30"
```

Unfortunately, I need to feed a type Diff into my Price(..) function to produce a type Diff, which then gets fed into my Differente(..) function to return another type Diff.

My C# function however works solely on doubles (and I would like it to stay this way, as it is used in other places in my C# program).

The only way I can think to solve this is to write every function twice, which is obviously awful as:

1) I may as well just write a differentiated version each time
2) This isn't a very expandable model

So is there any way I can get around this, or perhaps coerce my double functions into Diff functions (preferably in F#). Ideally I would just like to throw a (double -> double) function in and get a Diff.ToString() out.

Sorry if this totally vague or impossible to understand. I will answer any questions in comments if this is unclear.

I hope there is a solution for this! Thanks in advance,

Ashley

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. If I read your question correctly, it seems you want to be able to use your `Price` method (unmodified) as you use your example function `f`. But `f` uses your custom operators, while a C# method operating on doubles will always use the `double` operators.

Comment: Note that if you're only interested in the numerical value of the derivative and no symbolic term, just use an approximation formula: `f'(x) = (f(x+h)-f(x))/h` for some small `h`

Comment: @dtb Yes, you are exactly correct. Ideally I would like to use a transform/coerce on the functions parameters to get them from double to Diff.

Comment: @Dario Yes, I am only interested in the numerical derivative. However, using the approximation has two problems. 1) It is very inaccurate (for a price), 2) h needs to change from function to function and with variable x to optimize the method, hence I would prefer a more general one.

Comment: With `maturity=5`, `frequency=10`, `coupon=11` and `nominal=13` I get `Price(Id(2))==71.493`, `Differentiate(Price(Id(2)))==-423.782` and `Differentiate(Differentiate(Price(Id(2))))==5039.610`. Is that correct?

Comment: I get Price = 71.493 and Differentiate(Price) = -35.719

Comment: Then there's still a bug in my `Power` method... I've completed what I've started working on in my answer below. The approach works: you *can* have a single method that operates both on `double` and `Diff` values. But I think it's not really worth the hassle. Just create a second version of your `Price` method to operate on `Diff` values and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I agree, I think to achieve this it will take as much if not more effort/code than just implementing a Diff version.

Comment: Wouldn't quotations be an adequate solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-invent Haskell Type Classes:

```
interface Eq<T>
{
    bool Equal(T a, T b);
    bool NotEqual(T a, T b);
}

interface Num<T> : Eq<T>
{
    T Zero { get; }
    T Add(T a, T b);
    T Subtract(T a, T b);
    T Multiply(T a, T b);
    T Negate(T a);
}

sealed class Int : Num<int>
{
    public static readonly Int Instance = new Int();
    private Int() { }
    public bool Equal(int a, int b) { return a == b; }
    public bool NotEqual(int a, int b) { return a != b; }
    public int Zero { get { return 0; } }
    public int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    public int Subtract(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
    public int Multiply(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
    public int Negate(int a) { return -a; }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
static T F<M, T>(M m, T x) where M : Num<T>
{
    return m.Multiply(x, m.Multiply(x, x));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(F(Int.Instance, 5));  // prints "125"
}
```

And then with:

```
class Diff
{
    public readonly double d;
    public readonly Lazy<Diff> df;

    public Diff(double d, Lazy<Diff> df)
    {
        this.d = d;
        this.df = df;
    }
}

class DiffClass : Floating<Diff>
{
    public static readonly DiffClass Instance = new DiffClass();
    private static readonly Diff zero = new Diff(0.0, new Lazy<Diff>(() => DiffClass.zero));
    private DiffClass() { }
    public Diff Zero { get { return zero; } }
    public Diff Add(Diff a, Diff b) { return new Diff(a.d + b.d, new Lazy<Diff>(() => Add(a.df.Value, b.df.Value))); }
    public Diff Subtract(Diff a, Diff b) { return new Diff(a.d - b.d, new Lazy<Diff>(() => Subtract(a.df.Value, b.df.Value))); }
    public Diff Multiply(Diff a, Diff b) { return new Diff(a.d * b.d, new Lazy<Diff>(() => Add(Multiply(a.df.Value, b), Multiply(b.df.Value, a)))); }
    ...
}
```

You can do this:

```
static T Price<M, T>(M m, T _maturity, T _frequency, T _coupon, T _nominal, T yield) where M : Floating<T>
{
    T price;

    price = m.Zero;

    for (T index = m.Succ(m.Zero); m.Compare(index, m.Multiply(_maturity, _frequency)) <= 0; index = m.Succ(index))
    {
        price = m.Add(price, m.Divide(m.Multiply(m.Divide(_coupon, _frequency), _nominal), m.Power(m.Add(m.Succ(m.Zero), m.Divide(yield, _frequency)), index)));
    }

    price = m.Add(price, m.Divide(_nominal, m.Power(m.Add(m.Succ(m.Zero), m.Divide(yield, _frequency)), m.Multiply(_maturity, _frequency))));

    return price;
}
```

But that's not really pretty.

In fact, it almost reads like code that creates a LINQ Expression Tree. Maybe you can use *<strike>Source code</strike> Expression tree transformation* instead of *Operator overloading* to achieve *Automatic differentiation*?

Comment: Really would like a little more explanation, this answer would rock! Thanks though

Comment: This answer is abstraction overkill I think. See my answer below for a super easy C# implementation of automatic differentation that preserves most of the performance of the original function while permitting differentiation when needed.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to use your existing C# function, nor is there any easy way to lift it to a function that could operate on members of type `Diff`.  Once the function has been compiled it is opaque and the internal structure is unavaliable; all you can do is call the function with a double argument and get a double result.  Furthermore, your `Price` method uses operations which you haven't even defined on your `Diff` class anyway (`(\)` and `Pow`).

I'm not sure if it would be acceptable for your purposes, but one possible alternative would be to write a generic inline version of your `Price` function in F#, which could then operate on either doubles or `Diff`s (assuming that you add the `(\)` and `Pow` operators).

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers with "re-implementing type classes" are total overkill if you just need simple automatic differentiation. Use operator overloading and reify the derivatives as an array, as [I show in this project](https://github.com/naasking/AutoDiffSharp). The core type you need is just:

```
public readonly struct Number
{
    public readonly double Magnitude;
    public readonly double[] Derivatives;

    internal Number(double m, params double[] d)
    {
        this.Magnitude = m;
        this.Derivatives = d;
    }
}
```

Then implement the [operator translations shown on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Automatic_differentiation_using_dual_numbers), so each operator on Number also operates on the `Derivatives` array.

You need to define your functions as operating on this `Number` type, but by defining the full suite of arithmetic operators on `Number`, this is usually just changing the parameter types, and changing any calls to the static `Math.X` functions to a corresponding `Number.X` function, ie. `Math.Sin(x)` -> `x.Sin()`.

A null/empty array would mostly be operating on raw doubles, so it could be pretty close to the speed of the original code.